# Private project access token in GITLAB

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am developing a utility where I need to validate the user by taking username and validate it with a specific gitlab private repository members. If the user exists in that repository members then only the executable will run. As this utility will be used by many users,I do not want to use my personal access token.
I am new to Gitlab, would be great help if you can show possible options here.

Comment: Instead of supplying the personal access token via configuration, could you instead ask the user of the utility to provide their own token each time the utility is run? Something like: `./my-utility -token my-token`